# How to prompt the user to input the correct format of email address in C++?

Tags: c++

Basically, I wish to limit the user to input in the correct format of email address with the code below.

```
 cout << "Donor's Email: ";
 cin >> email;
     while (email != "@" && email != "."){
     cout << "Please enter correct email format." << endl;
     cout << "Donor's Email: ";
     cin >> email;
     }
```

Somehow, the results are, even I input the correct format of email address but it keeps on looping for me to input again.
Somebody please help me. Thanks.

Comment: `==` and `!=` compare the whole string. It looks like you actually want to check if it contains a character instead.

Comment: Have a look here for using regular expressions [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903985/email-validation-in-c]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you want the negation of your condition: i.e.

```
while (!(email != "@" && email != "."))
```

which, by application of De Morgan's law simplifies to

```
while (email == "@" || email == ".")
```

But this seems to me to be an insufficient check for validity (surely `"@@"` is invalid too, for example). Consider using the *regular expression* library `std::regex` &c. from C++11, having Googled "regular expression for a valid email address".

Comment: This won't help. It looks like this user is confusing equality checking with substring search. i.e. they want to check that the string contains both `@` and `.`.

Comment: Meh. The regular expression solution is still appropriate. And a character by character check will not weed out multiple `'@'``, unless you take extra steps.

Comment: But you didn't even provide that solution in your answer... and most of your answer is still incorrect.

Comment: @interjay: Perhaps you could show us all how it should be answered then?

Comment: I don't like answering such low-effort questions. But "google how to use regular expressions" is at best a comment. And I don't understand why you're leaving the first part of the answer up, given that it's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't try but if you're using C++11 you could use `std::regex`.

From [gonjay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903985/email-validation-in-c) your code could be something like:

```
 #include <regex>
 using namespace std;

 const regex pattern("(\\w+)(\\.|_)?(\\w*)@(\\w+)(\\.(\\w+))+");
 cout << "Donor's Email: ";
 cin >> email;
      while (!regex_match(email, pattern)){
      cout << "Please enter correct email format." << endl;
      cout << "Donor's Email: ";
      cin >> email;
      }
```

Comment: Could you fashion this into compilable code? Also, I shied away from supplying an actual regular expression since one that works for all possibilities doesn't exist!

Comment: I guess this is a quite complex matter. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

I know there are no regular expression that works for every email, but since that, to do this properly, the complexity would increase significantly, I decided to give a quick fix answer.

Again, didn't try this code.

Comment: Yes, it's not simple; I was thinking about pasting up the RFC 5322 regular expression in my answer, but thought better of it ;-) That all said, I think what you have is a good enough drop-in replacement for an upvote.

Comment: If you did, stack OVERFLOW would live up to its name